# How to restricts access to JSF application pages acceessed without having "faces" in URL

Tags: jsf, web-applications

I have a JSF web application which has URL like

```
http://host/app/faces/<page>.xhtml
```

*app* is context root, and */faces/** is Servlet URL pattern

where *page* can be any page from my application. Now if i access any page using this URL, I have access controller in places which redirect it *login.xhtml* if there is no active session of some backend service.

If i remove *faces* string from URL ,

```
http://host/app/<page>.xhtml
```

then some static content of pages is rendered.

My question is how do i stop this static content from rendering.

Answer (score 0):

just change your url pattern from `.xhtml` to `.html` 
and use security-constraint. this will restrict direct access to xhtml files.

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict direct access to XHTML files</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML Files</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

Comment: if you try in Chrome please open Network tab in developer tool. You can see which files not found.